# To obtain the value in a combo box from the database in c#

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

I have a form1 where the location ID and and the location name are the inputs and displayed.

Now at the same time I have a combobox and a textbox in another form

Now my question is: while we insert a new location in the form1 and insert it in the datagridview, I want the same to be inserted in the  combo box and textbox respectively.

I used the code

```
dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[1].Value.ToString()
```

but it works only for the row one and column 1.

private void gv_Location_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)

```
    {


        int i = gv_Location.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;


        label1.Text = gv_Location.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();


        label3.Text = gv_Location.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();

    }
```

now i have the values in the corresponding labels.and i want to insert these two values i.e locationID in a combo box and location name in a textbox which is located in another form

Comment: Please show the insertion code as well?

Comment: You need to replace `1` with a variable representing the right index, but there is insufficient information in this question for anybody to give an informed answer with regard to your specific situation.

Comment: in case you have 2 comboboxes in your gridview then do this  dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[2].Value.ToString(). Assuming Cells[2] contain your second combobox. But give more info to get a valid answer

Comment: i have edited the question. now somebody please help me,... this is my homework :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly add a new row in DataGridView it should be something like

dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count() + 1].Cells[1].Value.ToString()

To Add the data in combobox you can save the have it inserted in List or Dictionary and save in ViewState. Bind the casted ViewState to Dropdown so that every time page refreshes you retain the data in dropdown.

Hope this helps

Thanks